# A horizontal scrollbar appears after logging in with Google One Tap on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, google-signin, google-one-tap

I have integrated Google One Tap into my website. The login process works well on desktop, but on mobile, there is a horizontal scroll after logging in. It's also important to note that the direction of the website is right-to-left.

Following a user's sign-in, Google adds an empty `<div>` with the ID "g_a11y_announcement" at the end of the `<body>`:
[image: g_a11y_announcement div]

It has the following CSS attributes:

```css
#g_a11y_announcement {
    height: 1px;
    left: -10000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    width: 1px;
}
```

I get a blank screen right after signing in because of a 10,000 pixel overflow:
[image: blank screen]

Unfortunately, I can't share a link to my website, but taking this element out of the DOM removes the scrollbar.

There's no documentation on this `<div>` or how to tell Google One Tap that the page is right-to-left. The only solution I can think of is to override the CSS, but I don't want my application to be blocked by Google.

```css
#g_a11y_announcement {
    display: none;
}
```

What is the purpose of this `<div>`? Is there another solution that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem like you, I resolved for first moment this problem on next way:

after logout I redirected on login page by window.location, I know thats not right answer for this problem but that will resolve for first, problem is because in this solution app will refresh

Comment: Doing a full refresh will resolve the issue, but my website is a single-page application, and refreshing the page might result in data loss. Trying to save the data locally isn't realistic since Google One Tap can appear anywhere on the website.

Comment: I know, u are right, but in situation if u dont have a problem with refresh. I had different situation. I needed fix on any way. Thank you on answer

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hiding the div completely, I moved it to the right when the page direction is right-to-left. The solution below uses the [SASS parent selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) to check the direction.

```scss
#g_a11y_announcement {
  [dir="rtl"] & {
    left: auto;
    right: -10000px;
  }
}
```

The only downside to this solution is that it could break if Google changes the One Tap implementation.

Comment: Hi @Shachar, Did you figure out a solution for this in the meantime? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I used the solution I described above.

Answer (score 0):

I either did not found the reason for this div to appear or how to solve it, but in the meantime I ended up with the following solution:

```
body #g_a11y_announcement{
    display: none;
}
```

**Everyone - if you managed this out with a real solution please update!**
**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

quick patch:

```
#g_a11y_announcement {
    right: 0;
}
```